# Python game; Why can't I re-call my input and if/else function?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, input

I'm still kind of learning Python, but my friend who has programmed in Python before says this should work fine, but it wont?

All code before this was the beginning story for this basic "escape the room" game I'm making. The code up until here works, (basic print functions describing the game).

I give the player the scenario that they're in a room and they can do one of two things:

```
def intro_room_input():
    intro_action = input("What would you like to do? (Please enter either: 1 or 2) ")
    return intro_action;
```

These two functions are for when they choose 1 or 2, the next if/elif function runs these functions
If they choose 1:

```
def intro_room_result1():

print(
    """ 
    (Story stuff for the result of option 1. Not important to the code)
    """)

    return;
```

This function will play out if they choose 2

```
def intro_room_result2():

    print(
    """ 
    (Story stuff for the result of option 2. Not important to the code)

    """)

    return;
```

This will be the function for taking the player's input and continuing the story from there.

```
def intro_action_if(string):

    if string == "1":       
        intro_room_result1()
    elif string == "2":
        intro_room_result2()
    else:
        print("I'm sorry, that wasn't one of the options that was available..."+'\n'+
        "For this action, the options must be either '1' or '2'"+'\n'+
        "Let me ask again...")
        intro_room_input()
        intro_action_if(string)
    return;
```

that last intro_room_input runs fine, it re-runs the previous input, but when you actually enter 1 or 2, it doesn't do anything with them. It doesn't want to re-run the if/elif/else function to give the results.

finally I have a main that runs everything:

```
def main():
    string = intro_room_input()
    intro_action_if(string)
    return;


main()
```

Please help, I have no idea what's wrong with this code!?

Comment: This is what I see: in the else statement you are not assigning the result of `intro_action_if` to `string`, hence the call will do again the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `intro_action_if()`. When you are calling the function to get values again, you forgot to change the `string` value.

ie,

```
#intro_room_input()            #wrong

string = intro_room_input()    #right
intro_action_if(string)
```

As you can see, even though in your code you asked for the user `input` and `returned` it, you forgot to reassign `string` with the returned value. Hence it kept the same input you had given previously and passed that old value to `intro_action_if()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) re-assigning it in my function worked just like I wanted it to.